# How to make methods work if statements

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, methods

Im trying to get my method to work.
We are supposed to be creating a tax bracket and a method must be used.
(extremely unconventional. I know.)

I do not think my variables are right, or i do not have the right thing entered into my method statment.

This is also why when I try to call it, it does not work.

```
public class Assignment2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        double income1;
        double sttax;
        income1=0;
        sttax=0;


        System.out.println("This program is designed to have the user input ");
        System.out.println("their yearly income, and this program will give output for ");
        System.out.println("state and federal tax, gross and net pay for any given numeric input.\n"); 

        income1=in.nextDouble();

        sttax=sttax1(sttax);

        System.out.print(" "+ sttax);

    }
    public static double sttax1 (double income) {

        income=income1;

        if (income<1000)
            sttax=.02*income;

        if (1000>=income && income<2000)                       
            sttax=20+ (.03*(income-1000));

        if (2000>=income && income < 3000);                    
            sttax=50+ (.04*(income-2000));

        if (3000 >= income && income < 10000)                          
            sttax=90+ (.0475*(income-3000));

        if (100000>= income && income< 125000)             
            sttax=4697.50+ (.05*(income-100000));

        if (125000>= income && income < 150000)            
            sttax=5947.50+ (.0525*(income-125000));

        if (150000>= income && income < 250000)        
            sttax=7260.00+ (.055*(income-150000));

        if (income>=250000)                        
            sttax=12760.00+ (.0575*(income-250000));

        return sttax;

    }

}
```

Comment: change to else if instead of if. and your code will not compile.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile - you declare a method inside another method.

Comment: I edited your code to fix the formatting.  I only changed whitespace.  I did not remove any brackets.  That said, if your code is really in this form, you are missing a closing bracket to your `main` method, which means your code won't compile.

Comment: i took out that bracket so it would look right in stack overflow, sorry this is my first time using this website.  It will compile on my computer

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with your code:

- Your main method is missing a closing `}` at the end.
- Your `sttax1` method is expecting a parameter `income` to calculate the tax according to that `income`. When you call the method you should probably use the `income` that the user entered as a parameter. Right now you are using `sttax` as parameter which will be always 0 when you call `sttax1`.
- After you fixed the invocation of your `sttax1` method you can then simply use your method parameter (`income`) instead of `income1`.

Answer (score 0):

change your code as below. there was issue in **method calling**, **method inside method**, **use of variables out of scope**, **unnecessary use of variables**.

```
    public class Assignment2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        double income1;
        double sttax;
        income1=0;
        sttax=0;


        System.out.println("This program is designed to have the user input ");
        System.out.println("their yearly income, and this program will give output for ");
        System.out.println("state and federal tax, gross and net pay for any given numeric input.\n"); 

        income1=in.nextDouble();

        sttax=sttax1(income1);

        System.out.print(" "+ sttax);

       }
    public static double sttax1 (double income) {
      double sttax=0.0;    
        if (income<1000)
            sttax=.02*income;

        if (1000>=income && income<2000)                       
            sttax=20+ (.03*(income-1000));

        if (2000>=income && income < 3000);                    
            sttax=50+ (.04*(income-2000));

        if (3000 >= income && income < 10000)                          
            sttax=90+ (.0475*(income-3000));

        if (100000>= income && income< 125000)             
            sttax=4697.50+ (.05*(income-100000));

        if (125000>= income && income < 150000)            
            sttax=5947.50+ (.0525*(income-125000));

        if (150000>= income && income < 250000)        
            sttax=7260.00+ (.055*(income-150000));

        if (income>=250000)                        
            sttax=12760.00+ (.0575*(income-250000));

        return sttax;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the user input to `income1`, but you do not call your method with it. 
So first thing should be to call your method with the right parameter:

```
sttax = sttax1(income1);
```

Then you do not need this line:

```
income = income1;
```

The rest seems to be math only, so if there is an error you should check your calculations. Unless you have an actual exception thrown in your face, your code runs fine.

Maybe you should also look into Lazy evaluation if your result is not what you have expected. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation